# Visual Studio 2022 debugger not processing referenced dll code properly

Tags: debugging

I have a C# app using .Net framework 4.8 that references a dll from another project.  The code in the referenced dll project has 2 methods that look something like the following:

```
    string Method1(string caller)
    {
       return GetStringValue(caller, false, false);
    }
    string Method2(string caller, bool A, bool B)
    {   
      if (A)
        return "Monday";
      else if (B)
        return "Tuesday";
      else return "Something Else";
    }
```

I am not getting the expected value.
In debug mode, as I step through the code, it opens a screen similar to the code in the referenced dll, but not the same. It shows the original cs file name, but refers to a 'miscellaneous file' in the c:\users\appdata\local\temp folder.
The code it shows looks something like the following.

```
    string Method1(string caller)
    {
        return GetStringValue(caller, A: false, B: false);
    }
    string Method2(string caller, bool A, bool B)
    {
       if (A)
         return "Monday";  // => the debugger is stepping into this value
       if (B)
         return "Tuesday";
       return "Something Else"; // => the debugger is also stepping into this value
    }
```

The debugger doesn't let me see the actual values in this decompiled version, but I am not receiving the 'Something Else' value I would expect.
It's not clear what it is doing or why.

I've rebuilt the referenced dll's (release mode) and deleted all old versions.
I've deleted the .vs folder, restarted the server, downloaded and installed all the vs 2022 updates.

If I add the project for the referenced dll to this project, I get the expected value properly.